# AdMob using in splash screen

Tags: ios, ios7, admob, splash-screen, launch

```
 Bview=[[ADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 100)];
 [Bview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
 [self.view addSubview:Bview];
```

The Above code i used for displaying iAds.

Is this possible to adding AdMob or iAds or any other advertisement portions can able to adding / inserting of splash / launch screen using Xcode 6.0.

Comment: If you could be clearer with your question that would help immensely. I think you want to show an interstitial ad upon application launch? If so, just call and display an interstitial in the viewDidLoad section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use splash screen as a rootview controller.
Add background image of splash screen on that view controller.That means your view controller will act as splash screen. Here you can add your code for admob.Otherwise it is not possible.
One more thing, if ad takes much time to display on splash screen, apple can reject your app.
Reference from apple document-
"As much as possible, avoid displaying a splash screen or other startup experience. It’s best when users can begin using your app immediately."

Comment: @BHASKAR inspite of asking silly question here.. google it.. you will get plenty of websites :P